# How to perform regex-like search in Elasticsearch on a string not analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am struggling to find a way to query in Elasticsearch for occurrences of this log message:

```
Task my_celery.tasks.abc[d323a875-2a0e-41eb-896b-3f6d5f8aab9b] raised
unexpected: NameError("global name 'dfadgsdfgsdfg' is not defined",)
```

I want to detect these messages, so either looking for "Task ... raised unexpected" or "raised unexpected" is fine, but I cannot find a way to do it in Elasticsearch.

The field containing the message is not analyzed, which seems to prevent the usage of "regexp", "match" and "match_phrase" queries.

Do you know how I can make this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but beware of the wildcard use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "text": {
        "value": "*raised unexpected*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```